# i have made pencil drawing on group but it is drawing with some gaps leaving behind.how to make it smooth?

Tags: javafx

I am using adding circle on mouse drag with 5px of radius.It is eaving some gap behind .How to make it smooth.

```
public void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    Circle circleForShape = new Circle();
                    circleForShape.setCenterX(event.getX());
                    circleForShape.setCenterY(event.getY());
                    circleForShape.setRadius(5);
                    circleForShape.setSmooth(true);
                    circleForShape.smoothProperty();
                    circleForShape.setFill(c);
                    group.getChildren().add(circleForShape);
}
```

Nothing on Mouse Pressed & Mouse released event. Adding image for some clarity .
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess you've imported the "wrong" Label (e.g. from AWT), which doesn't extend `javafx.scene.Node`. Make sure it is from the `javafx.scene.control` package.

Comment: Ohh thanks you are right.